# Delphi 'The memory manager cannot be changed after it has been used' error on startup

Tags: delphi, memory-management, runtime-error, delphi-10.1-berlin

Recompiling a Delphi project in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, the system is throwing the following error at app startup:

> The memory manager cannot be changed after it has been used

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Well, this issue has been posted to help Delphi programmers save time. This is a random behavior happening on Delphi Berlin 10.1 and madExcept 4.0.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is not Delphi or the project code, a 3rd party '*MadExcept handler*' is causing the error.

To solve the issue, I removed the previously compiled `.dcu` files from my dcu folder, and rebuilt the project.

Comment: This beats no relation to the question that was asked. There's no way that you could tell from the question that madExcept is involved.